# Serialize same type objects to the same file

Tags: java, serialization

I want objects of a same serializable class to serialize in the same file. I have tried to do it by putting everything in an array and then serialize by I want the objects to be serialized individually and saved into the same file

Comment: Open an `ObjectOutputStream` to the file, and then call `writeObject` multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serialize multiple objects, why not serialize a collection of those objects? When you deserialize the collection you can access the objects again by iterating. Or if you have some unique identifer for the object you can put them in a map instead and serialize that.

Worth mentioning is that Java serialization will be going away in future with the newer versions. You are better off using a JSON serializer / de-serializer in my opinion, unless you of course are trying to hide the contents somehow. I use [FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML) myself and it works really great with POJOs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried this?

```
 FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("YourPath", true);
```

The true value as the second parameter allows you to write in this file in append mode.
So you can serialize them individually and they will be serialized in the same file.